# Creating a route to generated a barcode in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, url, routes

Im new to nodejs but I have experience in php, however, I am trying to create an endpoint on and nodejs app that generates a barcode from an orderId pass to it.  Trying to find out what is the best way to write this in node.

I've looked at the documentation and read thoroughly but I am confused between res.render and res.send and which should be use.

This is my code so far.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let codes = require("rescode");
let url = require('url');
var JsBarcode = require('jsbarcode');
var Canvas = require("canvas");

router.get('/barcode/:id', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('barCode', { title: 'barcode' });

   //I want to create a route that takes in and orderId, 
   //and uses the jsbarcade to generate a barcode

});

module.exports = router;
```

I want to be able to uses this end point to pass in and orderId from an email campaign and generate a barcode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the module [jsbarcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsbarcode)? I think it does the job what you want here.

Comment: Yes, what I am trying to do is to create an route URL that it can be used to pass in an order id, and then use the url to create a barcode.  Jsbarcode seems fairly easy to use, what i am trying to figure out is what is the best way to create a route in node for this type of case.

Answer (score 0):

Create base64text out of barcode image and use it anywhere.
Eg:-

```
var JsBarcode = require('jsbarcode');
var Canvas = require("canvas");
var canvas = new Canvas();
router.get('/barcode/:id', function(req, res, next) { 
var barcode=textToBase64Barcode(id);
    res.render('barCode', barcode); 
    }

function textToBase64Barcode(text){
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
jsBarcode(canvas, text, {format: "CODE39"});
return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 }
```

> Ps:- i have not tried out this. You might have to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Install libraries canvas and jscodebar:

```
npm install jsbarcode –save
npm install canvas
```

2.- Then use the code to generate the image. Replace "I love tacos" for your data request

```
    const { Canvas } = require("canvas");
    const jsBarcode = require('jsbarcode');
    const canvas = new Canvas();
    jsBarcode(canvas, 'I love tacos', {
        lineColor:"black",
        width: 2,
        height: '80px',
        displayValue: false
    });
    let imgBase64 = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        canvas.toDataURL('image/png',(err, imgBase64)=>{
            if (err) {
                reject(reject);
                return;
            }
            resolve(imgBase64);
        });
    });
    console.log(imgBase64);
```

3.- Return as you wish. On base64

```
    return res.json({imgBase64: imgBase64})
```

Or the image displayed on browser

```
    res.header('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename="file.png"`);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'image/png');
    const pdfBuffer = Buffer.from(`${imgBase64}`.replace('data:image/png;base64,',''), 'base64');
    return res.send(pdfBuffer);
```

Or as html document

```
    return res.send(`<img src="${imgBase64}" >`);
```